# Flashlight/ torch when streaming video

Tags: android, torch, tokbox

I want to switch on torch on Android devices when tokbox is streaming video, using it as a lantern.

Swith on and off the torch is pretty easy, but if you try when camera is already working it launch a error.

*Torch for camera "0" is not available due to an existing camera user*

I guess this is expected result, but I've seen some apps using the torch while streaming video.

Any clues?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the camera object inside the custom video capturer, [from opentok Android examples](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/tree/master/Custom-Video-Driver).